# Bash - remove specific textblock from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to remove a specific block of text from a file. I want to find the start of the text block to remove, and remove everything until a specific pattern is found.

Example string to search in:

```
\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component and then follow many more characters with various special characters -- / ending with another \n---\n that I dont want to remove
```

I want to remove everything, starting from this string match `\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component`

So basically, find pattern `\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component` and remove everything until I match the next `\n---\n`

Expected output here would be:

```
\n---\n that I dont want to remove
```

Things I tried with sed:

```
sed 's/\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component.*\n---\n//g'
```

Things I tried with grep:

```
echo $string  | grep -Ewo "\\\n---\\\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\\\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\\\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\\\n name: component"
```

Nothing really works. Is there any bash wizard that can help?

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question as your efforts, Thank you.

Comment: `s/--123456789[^-]*--/--/` ?

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question with examples I tried and a more accurate example of the string pattern I'm looking for, thank you :)

Comment: Are these `\n` literal characters OR they are new lines?

Comment: they are literal characters

Comment: @blaargh, ok so what is the expected output then?

Comment: I edited the question with expected output, thank you!

Comment: Can those start and/or end strings both occur multiple times in your input or do each of them only occur once or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using literal strings to avoid having to escape any characters and assuming your target string only exists once in the input:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        begStr  = ARGV[1]
        endStr  = ARGV[2]
        ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = ""
        begLgth = length(begStr)
    }
    begPos = index($0,begStr) {
        tail = substr($0,begPos+begLgth)
        endPos = begPos + begLgth + index(tail,endStr) - 1
        print substr($0,1,begPos-1) substr($0,endPos)
    }
' \
    '\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component' \
    '\n---\n' \
    "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
\n---\n that I dont want to remove
```

Comment: This does it 100%, even though the real file is 285k characters. Thank you very much! I would very much appreciate a step by step walkthrough through this AWK magic, so I can understand it better for the next time. Thank you anyways though, awesome!

Comment: One more question: Is there a way to set ARGV[1] not as string literal but via bash variable?

Comment: @blaargh I think it's pretty self-explanatory so I'm not sure what to usefully say about it. Is there any specific part of it you don't understand? As for using a bash variable - do `awk 'script "$var" file` instead of `awk 'script' 'string' file`.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Searching string `\\n---\\n# Source: app\/templates\/deployment.yaml\\n# template file\\napiVersion: apps\/v1\\nkind: Deployment\\nmetadata:\\n name: component` and making field separator as `\\\\n---\\\\n` then printing last field of that line.

```
awk -v OFS="\\\\n---\\\\n " -F'\\\\n---\\\\n ' '
/\\n---\\n# Source: \
app\/templates\/deployment.yaml\\n# template \
file\\napiVersion: apps\/v1\\nkind: Deployment\
\\nmetadata:\\n name: component/{
  print OFS $NF
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
\n---\n that I dont want to remove
```

Comment: You don't have a wildcard after `123456789` to match the middle part `hha faewb`

Comment: @Barmar, oh ok OP's post is edited, let me take new sample now.

Comment: sorry for the in between edit, it should be an accurate representation now. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @blaargh, not an issue, answer has been edited now, please do check once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this actually works, but not for my "real" string.. So I just added a real pseudonymised example.. sorry for the hassle. The real string is more complicated unfortunately..

Comment: @blaargh, oh ok. Then kindly update samples and try to make it near to your actual one so that we could try to help here 

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 its accurate now, sorry again!

Comment: @blaargh,  Sure, please try my edited code once and let me know if this edited code helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 hey, this worked on the example string but I couldn't get it to work on the target file, sorry. Maybe I didn't give enough information. The block to find is in the middle of a huge > 285k characters file with all kinds of special characters. What Ed Morton posted worked for me though :) Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in the regexp to match them literally.

If the part between `\\n---\\n123456789` and `\\n---\\n` can't contain another `-`, you can use

```
sed 's/\\n---\\n123456789[^-]*\\n---\\n//g'
```

This assumption is needed because `sed` doesn't support non-greedy quantifiers, and `.*` will match until the last `\\n---\\n`, not the next one.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically, find pattern `\n---\n123456789` and remove everything until I match the next `\n---\n`

Using gnu-awk it might be simpler by making `\n---\n` a record separator (a non-regex approach):

```bash
s='aaa aaa\n---\n123456789 hha faewb\n---\naaaaaa\n---\n67891 0238\n---\nbbbf bb'
awk -v RS='\\\\n---\\\\n' '$1 != 123456789 {ORS=RT; print}' <<< "$s"

aaa aaa\n---\naaaaaa\n---\n67891 0238\n---\nbbbf bb
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n---$/!{P;D};:a;N;//!ba
     s~\n---\n# Source: app/templates/deployment.yaml\n# template file\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n name: component.*~\n---~' file
```

Open a two line window and if the second line in the window does not match `\n---` print/delete the first of the lines and repeat.

If the second line matches `\n---`, gather up any following lines until another match is made and if the subsequent lines also match the required string, delete all lines up until the second match.

Otherwise print lines as normal.

N.B. This does not cater for two such matches in a row.